# HTTP Get request error "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, ssl, tls1.2

When I try to call a rest webservice(HTTP get) from my .net 3.5 winform application, I get the following error:

```
     `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. 
StackTrace:    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)`
```

The request runs fine when run from the browser.
So, is the problem related to server using higher tls protocol, which is not supported by .net 3.5?
Here is my code to call the webservice:

```
XElement response = XElement.Load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mostly likely reason is that the web server TLS 1.2. If you cant upgrade your .net framework then may be this will help:  https://github.com/juhovh/AaltoTLS
BTW, I've not used this third party code and dont endorse it - It is up to you to decide on its suitability.